# Fill missing values in the data.frame with the data from the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, fill, na

I'm trying to backfill a fully outerjoined table with nearest preceding column data.

The data frame I have looks like.. 
(No rows have both sides as NA and the table is sorted by date).

```
              date     X         Y
2012-07-05 00:01:19   0.0122     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:34   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:56   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 03:20:31   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:19:56   0.0121   0.028
2012-07-05 04:20:31   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:20:50   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:22:29   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 04:24:37   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 20:48:45   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 23:02:34    NA      0.029
2012-07-05 23:30:45    NA      0.029
```

with this, I'm looking to..

1. leave the non-data missing rows as it is.
2. If either one side is missing (NA), then fill it with the "nearest preceding" row which has valid opposite side's value.

And so as the result, I would like to have the table looking like...

```
              date     X         Y
2012-07-05 00:01:19   0.0122     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:34   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:56   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 03:20:31   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 04:19:56   0.0121   0.028
2012-07-05 04:20:31   0.0121   0.028
2012-07-05 04:20:50   0.0121   0.028
2012-07-05 04:22:29   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 04:24:37   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 20:48:45   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 23:02:34   0.0121   0.029
2012-07-05 23:30:45   0.0121   0.029
```

What kind of R commands can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package

```
dat <- read.table(text="2012-07-05 00:01:19   0.0122     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:34   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 03:19:56   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 03:20:31   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:19:56   0.0121   0.028
2012-07-05 04:20:31   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:20:50   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 04:22:29   0.0121   0.027
2012-07-05 04:24:37   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 20:48:45   0.0121     NA
2012-07-05 23:02:34    NA      0.029
2012-07-05 23:30:45    NA      0.029")

require("zoo")
na.locf(dat)
#           V1       V2     V3    V4
#1  2012-07-05 00:01:19 0.0122  <NA>
#2  2012-07-05 03:19:34 0.0121  <NA>
#3  2012-07-05 03:19:56 0.0121 0.027
#4  2012-07-05 03:20:31 0.0121 0.027
#5  2012-07-05 04:19:56 0.0121 0.028
#6  2012-07-05 04:20:31 0.0121 0.028
#7  2012-07-05 04:20:50 0.0121 0.028
#8  2012-07-05 04:22:29 0.0121 0.027
#9  2012-07-05 04:24:37 0.0121 0.027
#10 2012-07-05 20:48:45 0.0121 0.027
#11 2012-07-05 23:02:34 0.0121 0.029
#12 2012-07-05 23:30:45 0.0121 0.029
```

Comment: Thank you for your direction, it does work indeed and for some reason I had specify na.rm=F option and got what I exactly wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try this

```
> library(zoo)
> na.locf(Data)
                x     y
2012-07-17 0.0122  <NA>
2012-07-18 0.0121  <NA>
2012-07-19 0.0121 0.027
2012-07-20 0.0121 0.027
2012-07-21 0.0121 0.028
2012-07-22 0.0121 0.028
2012-07-23 0.0121 0.028
2012-07-24 0.0121 0.027
2012-07-25 0.0121 0.027
2012-07-26 0.0121 0.027
2012-07-27 0.0121 0.029
2012-07-28 0.0121 0.029
```

where `Data` is your `data.frame`

Comment: Nice answer... 5 minutes later than @GSee though. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'd better be faster the next time ;)

Comment: Thank you for the direction, can only pick one answer though :(