# How to na.locf in R without using additional packages

Tags: r, performance, missing-data, na

Given a vector such as (say) `c(2,NA,5,NA,NA,1,NA)` the problem is to "last observation carry forward" resulting in vector `c(2,2,5,5,5,1,1)`.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512147/fill-missing-values-in-the-data-frame-with-the-data-from-the-same-data-frame), `na.locf` from the `zoo` package can do this. However, given the simplicity of the problem, and the fact that this is to be performed many times from a "blank" R environment, I would like to do this *without loading packages*. Is there a way to do it simply and quickly using just basic R? (The vector may be long and may contain many consecutive NAs.)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1783275/172261

Comment: @Arun If it is the same *question*, then the accepted answer on that page would have been a valid answer here, which it isn't.

Comment: @AnandaMahto If there exists some (any) answer that is valid to questionA but not to questionB then it stands to reason that questionA != questionB. "How to move a balloon without touching it" is not a duplicate of "How to move a balloon" even if they have some common answers. (My other reason for not deleting this question is that that answer is really hard to find unless you were lucky enough to try the word "propagate", which I wasn't, and I suspect others won't be.)

Comment: @tennenrishin, fine. But there's no reason to *reopen*. I don't see anyone voting to *delete* the question, and as such, your question will still serve as a signpost to the other question (or an end to someone's searching, whatever the case may be).

Comment: @AnandaMahto, okay thanks. But how does one "reopen"? By responding to a comment? (And how does one see whether a question is closed?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracted from `zoo::na.locf.default`

```
fillInTheBlanks <- function(S) {
  L <- !is.na(S)
  c(S[L][1], S[L])[cumsum(L)+1]
}
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782704/propagating-data-within-a-vector/1783275#1783275).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using `rle`:

```
x <- c(2,NA,5,NA,NA,1,NA) 
x[is.na(x)] <- Inf
x[is.infinite(x)] <- with(rle(x), 
    rep(values[which(is.infinite(values)) - 1], lengths[is.infinite(values)])
)
# [1] 2 2 5 5 5 1 1
```

Comment: This fails if `x` already contains infinite

Comment: Hopefully, that is obvious.