# How to fill in the "succeeding" numbers whenever there is a 0 in R?

Tags: r, replace, numbers, sequence

I have a string of numbers:

```
n1 = c(1, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 10, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 19, 23, 0, 0)
```

I need to replace 0 with the corresponding number right "behind" it to get, while leaving the 0s in the tail alone (cause there is nothing right behind them):

```
n2 = c(1, 1, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 19, 19, 19, 23, 0, 0)
```

How can I get from n1 to n2?

This seems to be a much harder question than the one I've asked earlier:

[How to fill in the preceding numbers whenever there is a 0 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689985/how-to-fill-in-the-preceding-numbers-whenever-there-is-a-0-in-r)

where flodel has come up with an elegant solution:

```
n2 <- n1[cummax(seq_along(n1) * (n1 != 0))]
```

However, this solution does not work here; I've tried but failed to adapt the code.

Can someone else figure out an elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is similar to the linked duplicate, but not the same.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't also have `NA` in the vector, you can use `na.locf` from package `zoo`:

```
n1[n1==0] <- NA
n2 = na.locf(n1, na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=TRUE)
n2[is.na(n2)] <- 0
n2
## [1]  1  1  6  6 10 10 10 10 11 12 19 19 19 23  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `rle` approach:

```
out <- rle(n1)

locs <- out$values == 0 & !seq_along(out$values) %in% length(out$values)
out$values[locs] <- out$values[which(locs) + 1]
with(out, rep(values, lengths))

##  [1]  1  1  6  6 10 10 10 10 11 12 19 19 19 23  0  0
```

Comment: +1 for the use of rle in this case. There are a lot of examples where rle apply and this one is another nice one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flodel's suggestion in reverse

```
na = c(1, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 10, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 19, 23, 0, 0)
locf<-function(x) {
    x<-rev(x)
    a<-x[cummax(seq_along(x) * (x != 0))]
    c(rev(a), rep(0, length(x)-length(a)))
}
locf(na)
# [1]  1  1  6  6 10 10 10 10 11 12 19 19 19 23  0  0
```