# Recode a value in a vector based on surrounding values

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to programmatically change a variable from a `0` to a `1` if there are three `1`s before and after a `0`.

For example, if the number in a vector were `1`, `1`, `1`, `0`, `1`, `1`, and `1`, then I want to change the `0` to a `1`.

Here is data in the vector `dummy_code` in the `data.frame` `df`:

```
original_df <- data.frame(dummy_code = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

Here is how I'm trying to have the values be recoded:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(dummy_code = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

I tried to use [the function `fill` in the package `tidyr`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/tidyr/html/fill.html), but this fills in missing values, so it won't work. If I were to recode the `0` values to be missing, then that would not work either, because it would simply code every `NA` as `1`, when I would only want to code every `NA` surrounded by three `1s` as `1`.

Is there a way to do this in an efficient way programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840590/how-to-fill-in-the-succeeding-numbers-whenever-there-is-a-0-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `rle` alternative, using the `x` from @G. Grothendieck's answer:

```
r <- rle(x)
```

Find indexes of runs of three `1`:

```
i1 <- which(r$lengths == 3 & r$values == 1)
```

Check which of the "`1` indexes" that surround a `0`, and get the indexes of the `0` to be replaced:

```
i2 <- i1[which(diff(i1) == 2)] + 1
```

Replace relevant `0` with `1`:

```
r$values[i2] <- 1
```

Reverse the `rle` operation on the updated runs:

```
inverse.rle(r)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

---

A similar solution based on `data.table::rleid`, slightly more compact and perhaps easier to read:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(x)
```

Calculate length of each run:

```
d[ , n := .N, by = rleid(x)]
```

For "x" which are zero and the preceeding and subsequent runs of `1` are of length `3`, set "x" to `1`:

```
d[x == 0 & shift(n) == 3 & shift(n, type = "lead") == 3, x := 1]
d$x
# [1] 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: sorry to change the game halfway through, but could either be modified for runs of `3` or greater?

Comment: Yes, I assume you just need to change `== 3` to whatever condition you need, e.g. `>= 3`. Try! ;)

Comment: For the `data.table` example, this worked: `d[dummy_code == 0 & shift(n) >= 3 & shift(n, type = "lead") >= 3, dummy_code := 1]$dummy_code`. was wondering whether another value (i.e., `:= 1`) needed to be changed, but now see that's for what is recoded.

Comment: was wondering whether another value (i.e., `:= 1`) needed to be changed, but now see that's for what is recoded.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg I was a bit lazy when I borrowed the `x` from the other answer - less typing...Because you already have a `data.frame`, you can replace `d <- data.table(x)` with `setDT(original_df)`. Also note that the `x` is updated by reference (`x := 1`). I did the `$x` just to print the resulting vector.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner using `rollapply` from zoo:

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(c(0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0), 7, function(x) if (all(x[-4] == 1)) 1 else x[4])
##  [1] 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

**Note:** Input used was:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Is `x` in `c(0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0)` referring to input? If so, can we maybe change to disambiguate? Thanks

Comment: The answer does say "The input used was: `x <-` "

Comment: Yes, but not little confusing as also an `x` in lambda function? Thanks again