# efficient fill a data.frame with values above

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I like to fill data.frames like

```
key val
"A"   2
NA    9 
NA    5 
"B"   5 
NA    1 
"C"   6 
NA    9 
NA    1 
NA    0 
NA    1
```

with the "above" key instead of NA

```
key val
"A"   2
"A"   9 
"A"   5 
"B"   5 
"B"   1 
"C"   6 
"C"   9 
"C"   1 
"C"   0 
"C"   1
```

I can go through each line per hand and save the last valid key, but that is very slow. Do you know a efficient way? Perhaps with dplyr?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yet another `zoo::na.locf` question it seems. Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11512236/3001626)?

Comment: Easy with a for loop, but I suppose there is some vector logic that would do it too, kind of late in the evening for me to think of it though.

Comment: Wow, zoo is pretty interesting.